# Comparing differentiability in real and complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know why differentiability in complex plane is stronger than differentiability in R^2? or for example for which reason analytic functions are different from smooth functions from R^2to R^2?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A differentiable function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ has Jacobian some $2 \times 2$ matrix everywhere. For it to be complex differentiable the Jacobian must be multiplication by a complex number, so is a rotation-and-scaling matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ -b & a \end{array} \right]$. This is a strong condition.

Comment: complex differentiable functions satisfy an elliptic partial differential equation $\partial_{\bar z} f=0$ and that already implies very strong properties

Comment: from directional derivative how can we conclude differentiability in complex plane is stronger ?